# how to generate amplitude modulated sine wave in iphone sdk?

Tags: iphone, sdk, audio-recording

I need to get the amplitude while recording. From that i've to construct a sine wave which is amplitude modulated one. How to get the amplitude of the sound? Please give me suggestions.

Comment: The question seems unclear.  Do you want to generate a sine wave and play it out the speaker?  Or record audio input from the mic and estimate the amplitude of some portion of the spectrum?

Comment: i'm going to take audio input from mic and convert the audio samples to sine wave. How to convert the audio input to amplitude modulated sine wave?

Answer (score 0):

Just generating sine wave is easier. 
Well, I implemented sine wave into the UIView drawrect method as follows :

```
float x=75;
float yc=50;
float w=0; 
 while (w<=rect.frame.size.width) {
CGPathMoveToPoint(path, nil, w,y/2);
CGPathAddQuadCurveToPoint(path, nil, w+x/4, -yc,w+ x/2, y/2);
CGPathMoveToPoint(path, nil, w+x/2,y/2);
CGPathAddQuadCurveToPoint(path, nil, w+3*x/4, y+yc, w+x, y/2);
CGContextAddPath(context, path);
CGContextDrawPath(context, kCGPathStroke);
w+=x;
}
```

Here x would be the width of each sine wave, while y is the height of the frame. This would draw number of sine waves to fit in the whole UIViewFrame. It would produce crisp looking sine wave and yc being control handle. Try it you might like it.

If the width ie. x is similar to the width of the frame then a single sine wave will be produced.

Number of complete sine wave = (width of frame) / ('x' width of each sine wave)
Now, try to adjust the amplitude and frequency of the wave with respect to the power of audio.